# Confusion with the の particle

Tags: translation, words, meaning, particles, particle-の

I am currently learning basic grammar using the Tae Kim's guide to japanese. In one of his examples he roughly translates this sentence:

> こんな**の**を本当に食べる？

as "*Do you think [he/she] will really eat this type of thing?*"

My question is, how does the possessive **の** particle make this sentence different from for example:

> こんなを本当に食べる？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

の here is not a possessive の, it's a nominalizer, a formal noun. こんな is adjectival and cannot by itself constitute a noun phrase.

In other words, こんな means "this type of", こんなの means "this type of thing".